# Netbeans hibernate MS SQL Server 2005 Exception

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, exception, netbeans

I am trying to configure Hibernate with NetBeans 7.2 to connect to a MS SQL 2005 server(localhost). Whenever I try to input a query to test at HQL Query0 window I get Exception dialog that says only my driver class name which is "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" with big red 'X' icon and OK button below even before I finish typing the query line. It's like hibernate doesn't even see the driver at all.

I configured everything as instructed by Netbeans website and consulted some online search result that seemed to relevant to my case. I checked and re-checked every line. The connection was successful when I made one at services tab with 'new connection' wizard thingy. 
Dose my Windows 7 OS being 64-bit Home premium edition have something to do with this? I am very frustrated. Please help!

BTW, my colleague with a same code (His might be 32bit Win 7) have no problem with the same test.